# Boolean column to determine if datetime index is between 8am and 9pm?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and was trying to create a new column of boolean values that would be generated based on my datetime index. A value of 1 if the hour is >= 08:00:00 and <= "21:00:00" and if the hour is outside of that range than 0.

```
Timestamp            Bath_County_Gen         Wing_Gen    Boolean
2020-09-23 00:00:00    -390.0                 2954.0        0
2020-09-23 00:15:00    -363.33                3007.75       0
2020-09-23 00:30:00    -250.0                 3049.0        0
2020-09-23 00:45:00    -220.0                 3143.5        0
2020-09-23 01:00:00    -206.67                3193.33       0
2020-09-23 01:15:00    -185.0                 3195.25       0
```

I tried the following but had no luck and wasn't sure how else to dynamically the boolean column value.

```
df['boolean'] = np.where(df.between_time('08:00:00', '21:00:00'), 1,0)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

After ensuring your `"Timestamp"` column is in datetime format, you can extract the hour of the day from it and perform the following operation:

```py
df['Timestamp'] = df.Timestamp.apply(pd.to_datetime) # ensure it's datetime
df['is_between_8_and_21'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.hour.between(8, 21, inclusive=True) # extract the hour and check if it's between 8 and 21h
```

now `df` will look like this:

```sh
Timestamp           Bath_County_Gen Wing_Gen    is_between_8_and_21
2020-10-23 00:00:00 -390.00         2954.00     False
2020-10-23 00:15:00 -363.33         3007.75     False
2020-10-23 00:30:00 -250.00         3049.00     False
```

Note that 21:05 will be translated to 21, so it will be included if you set the flag `inclusive=True`.

---

EDIT

As you mention, your "Timestamp" is actually a DateTime index. In this case, as you suggested you can already directly operate on the dataframe:

```
df.between_time('8:00', '21:00', include_start=True, include_end=True)
```

From the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) on `.between_time()`, it appears that if you specify the `start_time` and `end_time` as strings, they must be in a format as `"08:25"`, or `"21:51"`. If you want more fine-grained control to the second, you can use the alternative specification via `datetime.time`, so for example:

```py
import datetime
start_time = datetime.time(8, 0, 0)
end_time = datetime.time(21, 0, 0)    
df.between_time(start_time, end_time, include_start=True,
    include_end=False) # to ensure 21 o'clock exactly is excluded
```

Comment: Does this account for time like 21:01:00?

Comment: timestamp is a datetime index

Comment: @HenryYik I clarified in the answer. `21:01:00` 's `hour` is 21, so yes, in the current example `21:01:00` will be included as `True`. To circumvent that by using this approach you could say `.dt.hour.between(7, 21, inclusive=False)`. In this case 7:59 will not be included but 8:00 will, and 21:00 will not be included, while 20:59 will.

Comment: @EdiLacic you are right, I amended my response to address that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Timestamp column has datetime format:

```
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])
```

Afterwards you can access the hour with `datetime.hour`. Full code (I added two rows for testing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Timestamp": ["2020-09-23 00:00:00", "2020-09-23 00:15:00", "2020-09-23 00:30:00", "2020-09-23 00:45:00", "2020-09-23 01:00:00", "2020-09-23 01:15:00", "2020-09-23 15:15:00", "2020-09-23 23:15:00"]
})
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])

def is_between_8_and_21(datetime):
    return 1 if (datetime.hour >= 8) & (datetime.hour <= 21) else 0

df["Boolean"] = df["Timestamp"].apply(lambda x: is_between_8_and_21(x))
df
```

[image]